# Reflection Activator.CreateInstance() Saying Variables Are NULL

Tags: c#, system.reflection

```
string to = "user@example.com";
string from = "user@example.com";
string title = "Test";
string body = "Test Email";

Type t1 = Type.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailMessage");
Object test = Activator.CreateInstance(t1, new object[] { to, from, title, body });
```

I'm trying to use reflection (don't ask why) for System.Net.Mail.
Right now when I run and compile, it says to, from, title, and body are NULL (System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.)

Why is this happening? and if I replace the variables with what they are defined with it works fine.

EDIT 1 Full Error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at mcclureski.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Test\Program.cs:line 67
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter from [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) is a [params array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params), so  don't instantiate the object array, just place the argument in the correct order for your type construction:

```
Object test = Activator.CreateInstance(t1, to, from, title, body);
```

Comment: That didnt seem to work either. still System.ArgumentNullException. It just doesnt seem to want to use variables in createinstance

Comment: what do you get for t1?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but i added the full error to OP.

Comment: From your op: Type t1, anyway, what do you have in Program.cs:line 67?

Comment: Line 67 is the last line of the code i provided and type t1 is the system.net.mail